# Query album by name(Graph API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

We are going to migrate to the Graph API in FQL.

Using the name of the query conditions to query albumid/objectid.

FQL syntax used to do the following:

---

SELECT aid, object_id

FROM album

WHERE owner=0000 AND name=abcd

ORDER BY modified DESC
LIMIT 1

---

Is it possible to implement Graph API in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible unfortunately. There are no filtering methos available. You'll have to query for all albums and then filter in your application, and then query for the `album_id` you selected

E.g.

```
 /me/albums?fields=id,name
```